# What does the arm assembler code .long do in the below piece of code?

Tags: assembly, arm, boot

atags:

```
@ ATAG_CORE
.long   2
.long   0x54410001

@ ATAG_CMDLINE
.long   (1f - .) >> 2
.long   0x54410009
```

I was just going through a boot wrapper code for ARM .The section where  ATAG Tag is defined,I am not able to understand the instruction :

.long   (1f - .) >> 2

what does this instruction do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an ARM expert, but in other assemblers this would mean

`1f` = address of the next label (1 forward)
`.`  = current location

`1f - .` would then be the distance (in bytes) to the next label

If you divide this by 4 (`>> 2`), you get the distance in longs instead of bytes.

Comment: Thanks.I got it from your explanation.This step just calculates the size of the cmdline arguments( which follows this line ) in word.